# Using after to clean up in mocha, problems with mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb, coffeescript, mocha.js

Ok, in the after function `console.log "enter after function"` and `console.log "exit"` executes, but `console.log "WHYYYY"` does not execute. I can't figure out why. For the record, `console.log 'insert'` does execute. I am making a similar call to mongo in one of my tests, so calling mongo should work.

Any clues to this problem or how to resolve it?

```
describe 'HTTP Requests', ->
    describe 'Socky', ->
        socky = new Socky config
        socky.listen()

        before ->
            mongo.open (error, db) =>
                secondDb = db.db config.api.accountTest
                secondDb.collection 'accounts', (error, accountsColl) =>
                    accountsColl.insert {'_id': ObjectID("#{ accountId }"), 'name': "test-account"}, (error, records) =>
                        console.log 'insert'
                        db.close()
                        return

                db.collection 'tokens', (error, tokensColl) =>
                    tokensColl.insert {'accountId': "#{ accountId }", 'userId': "#{ userId }", 'token': 'testtoken'}, (error, records) =>
                        null
                        db.close()
                    return
                db.close()
                return

        after ->
            console.log "enter after function"

            # console.dir mongo
            mongo.open (error, db) =>
                console.log "WHYYYY"
                secondDb = db.db config.api.accountTest
                console.log error


                secondDb.collection 'accounts', (error, accountsColl) =>
                    accountsColl.remove {}, (error, records) =>
                        console.log "remove?"
                        null
                        return

                db.collection 'tokens', (error, tokensColl) =>
                    tokensColl.remove {}, (error, records) =>
                        # db.close()
                        return
                return
            console.log "exit after"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongo doesn't have enough time to connect,

Try using the done callback in after function:

```
after (done) ->
  console.log "WHYYYY"
  mongo.open (error, db) =>
     ...
     done()
  console.log "exit after"
})
```